# Send protobuf enum message to a grpc server

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

Given a

```
message Foo {
enum State {
    STATE1 = 0;
    STATE2 = 1;
    STATE3 = 2;
}
}
```

and a grpc service definition of

```
rpc Method(stream Foo) returns (Empty) {}
```

What does the go grpc client code to send this to a grpc server look like? To clarify, suppose I have a `streamClient.Send()`. What would I pass to `Send()`? How do I construct the enum?

Comment: I think you need to compile the protocol buffer definition, it will produce files with suffix `pb.go`

Answer (score 0):

You define State but you do not have a State field in Foo.

Try this

```
syntax="proto3";
option go_package ="enumpb";
message Foo {
  enum State {
    STATE1 = 0;
    STATE2 = 1;
    STATE3 = 2;
  }
  State myState = 1;
}
```

And this in go

```
enumExample := enumpb.Foo{
    MyState: enumpb.Foo_STATE1,
}
fmt.Println("enumExample", enumExample)
```